# Does "used as non-type template parameter" make a function template implicitly instantiated?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-templates, non-type-template-parameter, implicit-instantiation

I want to write a class template `M` that accepts incomplete type `C` as template parameter.
But I also want `C` has some traits when it is eventually defined.

Is this code guaranteed

- to compile if defined(FLAG),
- and to fail the compiling if !defined(FLAG)?

```
template <auto> struct Dummy {};

template <typename C>
void check()
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<C>);
}

template <typename C>
struct M : Dummy<&check<C>>
{
    //static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<C>);//error: incomplete type
    C * p;
};

struct Test;
M<Test> m;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

#if defined(FLAG)
struct Test {};
#else
struct Test { std::string non_trivial_member; };
#endif
```

Comment: I suspect at `M<Test>` that your code is already ill-formed ndr.  But am not certain.  I have vague memory of a clause involving at point of instantiation and end of compilation unit, intended to give the compiler freedom to defer instantiating the `Check` body, but requiring either spot to give the same result.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: As I remember, rules are different for classes and functions. class is instantiated only once, whereas function instantiation should "respect" ODR (and so be identical for each POI (and EOF is a possible POI)).

Comment: so issue would be with `check<C>` but not `M<C>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 But the POI of `check<C>` on `struct M : Dummy<&check<C>>` is the `M<Test>` line, no?  Ie, if `Test` where defined after `M` was, `M<Test>` would be ok (anything else is madness).

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: I would say `M<Test>` instantiates `check<Test>`, and for EOF `check<Test>` again. So `M<Test>` is instantiated once with incomplete `Test`, and check twice, one with incomplete `Test`, and one with complete `Test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From a n4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf),

### Point of instantiation [temp.point] (17.7.4.1/8)

> A specialization for a function template, a member function template, or of a member function or static data member of a class template may have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a point of instantiation. A specialization for a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a translation unit.  A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units.  If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule (6.2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

First, note that the primary template being paa0ssed arguments a specialization in standard speak.  C++ programmers use it differently than the standard does in my experience.

Second, `check<Test>` has two points of instantiation in your program; once at

```
M<Test> m;
```

and once at the end of the translation unit.

The meaning of `check<Test>` at `M<Test> m` is different than the meaning of `check<Test>` at the end of the translation unit.  At one spot, `Test` is incomplete, at the other it is complete.  The body of `check<Test>` definitely has a different meaning.

So your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  In your case, the ill-formed program happens to do what you want, but it could (under the standard) compile to anything at all, or fail to compile.

I suspect the reason behind this rule is to give the compiler the freedom to instantiate `check` either immediately or to defer it until later.  You are not allowed to rely on which of the two spots it actually does the instantiation of the body of `check`.